# icpc error #10104: unable to open 'tbb_placeholder' BOOST + ICPC + TBB + C++11

Tags: c++, boost, tbb, icc

I was trying to compile a boost+Intel TBB code using intel compiler (ICC-13.0.1) The TBB library is latest (4.2) and boost is 1.55.0. The code incorporates C++11 features and so I use the std=c++11 flag

I am getting this error:

```
icpc: error #10104: unable to open 'tbb_pLaCeHoLdEr'
make: *** [driver.o] Error 1
```

My Makefile contents are as follows:

```
INCLUDE_PROJECT = /home/aniketnp/multiproc/
INCLUDE_BOOST   = /home/aniketnp/boost_1_55_0/
TBB_L = /home/aniketnp/tbb42_20140122oss/lib/intel64
TBB_I = /home/aniketnp/tbb42_20140122oss/include



 CXXFLAGS = -I$(INCLUDE_PROJECT) -I$(INCLUDE_BOOST) -I$(TBB_I) -L$(TBB_L) -tbb -lpthread -std=c++11
```

Could any body speculate what could be the possible error?

1. The boost and TBB are in my home directory.
2. The ICC13.1 is loaded through a module in our cluster.
3. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable correctly shows the TBB_L  variable in makefile (properly exported in the .bashrc file.

Comment: unable to open usually means open failed, which usually happens because you don't have permissions, or it doesn't exist when you expect it to, or it does when you don't... did you do `sudo make` before and are doing `make` now or is tbb_pLaCeHoLdEr a variable that should have been expanded?

Comment: I cant do sudo make as i am not root. I just load the intel compiler module and i can start using the compiler. tbb_pLaCeHoLdEr is not a variable as such. i dont know from where it is coming

Answer (score 0):

looks like installation error of something that uses TBB. TBB has similar place in tbbvars.sh scripts but uses 'SUBSTITUTE_INSTALL_DIR_HERE' instead. So, search for `tbb_pLaCeHoLdEr` in your project and its components and replace accordingly